# Get the value of an Object in Handlebars with a key

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have an array of objects (vehicles) and i would like to get the value of the objet by giving a key in handlebars.

This is the array:

```
"vehicles": [
      {
        "value": "Car",
        "key": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "Motorbike",
        "key": "0"
      }
    ],
```

and I have a variable called vehicleKey. And I would get the vehicle with the "vehicleKey". I tried something like....

```
<p>
{{#vehicles}}
   {{key}}: {{../vehicleKey}}
{{/vehicles}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
<ul>
  {{#each vehicles}}
  <li>{{value}}</li>
  <li>{{key}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! but I would only like the vehicle with "vehicleKey" key :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the string key and vehicle try this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each vehicles}}
  <li>vehicle: {{value}}</li>
  <li>key: {{key}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! but I would only like the vehicle with "vehicleKey" key :)